# Add custom DNS Server IP to an Azure VM NIC using Terraform

Tags: configuration, dns, terraform, ip, nic

How to point to custom DNS IP using terraform IP Configuration block, sample code show below, is this valid?

```
  resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    dns_servers                   = 8.8.8.8,8.8,8.8
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

as per terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_interface#dns_servers)

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_servers         = ["8.8.8.8","1.1.1.1"]

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```